# Saving timestamp on IBrokers package

Tags: mysql, r, ibrokers

I am having some issues accessing the timestamp data in the IBrokers package.

Here is an example of the data I get:

```
                    AAPL.Open AAPL.High AAPL.Low AAPL.Close AAPL.Volume AAPL.WAP AAPL.hasGaps AAPL.Count
2015-01-09 17:59:00       112    112.04   111.95        112        6043  112.011            0       2240
```

So when I run `data[,0]` I get

```
2015-01-09 17:59:00
```

The problem is that later on when I try to save that into a `MySQL` table I get the following error:

```
Error in dimnames(cd) <- list(as.character(index(x)), colnames(x)) : 
  'dimnames' applied to non-array
```

It looks like `data[,0]` does not simply contains the timestamp.

When I do a summary of the variable `ts` which contains `data[,0]` I get:

```
Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("ts.1", "ts.0")) : 
  'names' attribute [2] must be the same length as the vector [1]
```

Any tip on how to access the timestamp or convert the contents of `ts` to char so I can insert it into the DB will be appreciated.

EDIT:

`dput()` output

```
structure(c(112, 112.04, 111.95, 112, 6043, 112.011, 0, 2240), .Dim = c(1L, 
8L), index = structure(1420837140, tzone = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tclass = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), .indexTZ = "", tzone = "", .Dimnames = list(NULL, 
    c("AAPL.Open", "AAPL.High", "AAPL.Low", "AAPL.Close", "AAPL.Volume", 
    "AAPL.WAP", "AAPL.hasGaps", "AAPL.Count")), class = c("xts", 
"zoo"), from = "20150112  02:52:24", to = "20150112  02:53:24", src = "IB", updated = structure(33434342.12435, class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")))
```

Comment: What is the structure of the original `AAPL` data? Can you run`dput()` or `str()` on it please? I have never seen `data[,0]` indexing, but it seems to return an empty matrix with the rownames - you may be better off just doing `rownames(data)` to get the timestamp.

Comment: Why are you subsetting by 0? You know R uses 1-based indexing, right?

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich That was the only way I found to access the timestamp. If I did data[,1] then I get `AAPL.Open`. But I am learning R so my approach might be wrong, it simply was the only thing that returned me the timestamp. Any tip on how to do it will be appreciated.

Comment: Read the zoo and xts vignettes.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich Thanks, zoo did it. time(ts) was my answer. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @JordanBelf If you find your own answer you should answer your question, that way you can contribute and help others. Or ask to JordanBelf to add an answer of his own since he mentioned where/how to find your answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @JoshuaUlrich on the comments to my question, the answer was on the `zoo` package.

Full documentation on zoo can be found [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/vignettes/zoo-quickref.pdf)

In my particular case by including the zoo library and simply doing:

```
time(data[,0])
```

I solve the `Error in dimnames()` error.

Hope it helps someone else.

Comment: No need for the indexing at all. Just `time(data)` will do it.